# 'Arrays as attribute arguments is not CLS-compliant' warning, but no type information given

Tags: .net, csc, cls-compliant

When compiling my solution, I get several warnings of the following:

> warning CS3016: Arrays as attribute arguments is not CLS-compliant

No other information on what type is not compliant is given. In my projects I have some attributes that take `params` array arguments in their constructors, but they are all internal, and that shouldn't affect CLS-compliance. Why is this warning being given, and what type is it being given on?

Comment: Did you find an easy way of finding where the warning was being caused?

Answer (score 8):

[CS3016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs3016).

If you have an attribute which takes an array as argument and the project is marked as [CLSCompliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx) you will get this warning.

Comment: But the attribute is internal to the assembly - not publically accessible. That should not affect the CLS compliance.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this today.  I had 4 instances of the warning showing up.  I then found that I had the attribute decorating 4 public methods in that assembly.  As I removed them one by one, the errors went away one by one.

Also, if you are OK with not being CLS compliant, you can put [CLSCompliant(false)] on the methods decorated with the attribute (or the class on which the methods are defined). Putting it on the offending attribute constructor/class doesn't do the trick. I guess this makes sense since ultimately the attribute is probably exposed outside the assembly as part of the public method's metadata.

Comment: Also, if you are OK with not being CLS compliant, you can put [CLSCompliant(false)] on the methods decorated with the attribute (or the class on which the methods are defined).  Putting it on the offending attribute constructor/class doesn't do the trick.  I guess this makes sense since ultimately the attribute is probably exposed outside the assembly as part of the public method's metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and what I had to do was to use the "Find in Files" dialog in VS2010 select Use: Wildcards and in the Find What: text box, enter

```
\[*\(*\)\]
```

That produces a list of all attribute instances. Went one by one and I was able to identify and correct the warnings.